# Android Search Expandable ListView

Tags: java, android

I am building my first android app and I encountered a problem. In the app I have a search function that uses a ListView. Here users can search for a certain item and see if it exists. This works really well and I did it based on this tutorial: [Android ListView with Search](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items)

All my items are found in a string array defined in array.xml. Now, every item can be part of one or more collections. Currently I show the collections it is included in next to the item's name, like this: "**ITEM -> Collection(s)**". This works but is not really an elegant option. What I would like to do is have the item's name as the ITEM in an expandable ListView and the collections it belongs to as a SUBITEM. I would therefore have 2 string arrays, one for the parent items, one for the children items.

All the examples I have found are populating the list "manually" and I can not figure out how to assign my ITEMS array to the GROUP and my COLLECTIONS array to the CHILDREN.

I don't know if I explained this clearly enough but in short, it would be like this:

ITEM_1 = 1st Group name
COLLECTIONS_1 = 1st Group's child

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0uYs.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really want an expandable list view, or do you want a two line list view where the top is the Item and the bottom the collections?  What you're showing in the image looks like the latter to me rather than the former.

Comment: I guess that for now the 2-line solution would also work. I semi-implemented that idea by using something like this:  "ITEM \r\n -> Collection(s)" when defining the string array items. Now the Collections are on the second row. Would it be possible to format these differently than the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Ok, managed to create the expandable view like I wanted it like this:

```
public class Search extends ListActivity {
    private String[] l1;
    private String[] l2;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
        String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> buildData() {
        l1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
        l2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.collections);
        Integer i;
        int to = l1.length;
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();     
        for(i=0;i < to;i++){
        list.add(putData(l1[i], l2[i]));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item.put("name", name);
        item.put("purpose", purpose);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Problem now is, how can I sort this?

Comment: if you have a follow-up question, consider posting a new one  or edit the current (hiding it in your answer is unlikely to help as nobody expects it there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You download the source code from here ([Expandablelistview with searchview in android](http://deepshikhapuri.blogspot.in/2018/02/expandablelistview-with-searchview-in.html))

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView ev_list;
    List> lv_country = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    EditText et_search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        ev_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ev_list);
        et_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

        fn_arraylist();
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(lv_country, getApplicationContext());
        ev_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        ev_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < customAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            ev_list.expandGroup(i);
        }


        et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                if (et_search.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(lv_country, getApplicationContext());
                    ev_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    for (int i = 0; i < customAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                        ev_list.expandGroup(i);
                    }
                } else {

                    List> lv_search = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < lv_country.size(); i++) {
                        List> lv_searchstate = new ArrayList<>();

                        List> lv_state = (List>) lv_country.get(i).get("State");
                        for (int j = 0; j < lv_state.size(); j++) {
                            if (lv_state.get(j).get("Name").toString().toLowerCase().contains(et_search.getText().toString())) {
                                lv_searchstate.add(lv_state.get(j));
                            }
                        }

                        if (lv_searchstate.size() != 0) {
                            HashMap hashMap_search = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap_search.put("Name", lv_country.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                            hashMap_search.put("State", lv_searchstate);

                            lv_search.add(hashMap_search);
                        }
                    }


                    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(lv_search, getApplicationContext());
                    ev_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    for (int i = 0; i < customAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                        ev_list.expandGroup(i);
                    }


                }

            }
        });


    }
```

Thanks!